# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field android.widget.TextView $ViewHolder.numberTextView on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, listview, nullpointerexception, textview

I've been working on a project recently, and I've been getting quite a strange error and I can replicate it on many devices. The thing is that the ListView in questions works for the first 10-20 items(the total item count is 24), but after that if I scroll downwards it throws an exception. Do you think that this is an Android issue and that I should just switch to recyclerView? Here is my activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    ArrayList<Item> listViewArrayList;
    ListView itemlistView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
                .applicationId("DAaBpKeoV0llJaxlHJGDP0cR6nkSWa5lV0qADN3R")
                .clientKey("LAm9wqXDaLoHnhXzGe6uXmzJGkcIuAnuZDSXRDwW")
                .server("https://parseapi.back4app.com")
                .build()
        );
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                for (Item item : listViewArrayList) {
                    jsonArray.put(item.toJsonObject());
                }
                Log.i("tag", jsonArray.toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OrderSendActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("orderJson", jsonArray.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        listViewArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> menuQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Menu");
        menuQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Download Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    for (ParseObject item : objects) {
                        listViewArrayList.add(new Item(item.getString("name"), item.getString("pricestring"), item.getInt("pricenumber")));
                    }
                    Log.i("debug", listViewArrayList.toString());
                    ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.layout, listViewArrayList);
                    Log.i("debug", adapter.toString());
                    itemlistView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
                    itemlistView.setAdapter(adapter);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Download Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.nav_first_layout) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_second_layout) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_third_layout) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView nameTextView;
        private TextView priceTextView;
        private Button plusButton;
        private Button minusButton;
        private TextView numberTextView;
    }

    private class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
        private ArrayList<Item> itemModelList;
        private int resource;


        ItemAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Item> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            itemModelList = objects;
            this.resource = resource;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

            final ViewHolder holder;
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            if (convertView != null) {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            } else {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.nameTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
                holder.priceTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.priceTextView);
                holder.plusButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.plusButton);
                holder.minusButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.minusButton);
            }


            holder.numberTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.numberTextView);
            holder.nameTextView.setText(itemModelList.get(position).getName());
            holder.priceTextView.setText(itemModelList.get(position).getPrice());
            holder.numberTextView.setText("0");
            holder.plusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    itemModelList.get(position).incrementOrderNo();
                    holder.numberTextView.setText(Integer.toString(itemModelList.get(position).getOrderNo()));
                }
            });
            holder.minusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    itemModelList.get(position).decrementOrderNo();
                    holder.numberTextView.setText(Integer.toString(itemModelList.get(position).getOrderNo()));
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

My layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="88dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingStart="?listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingEnd="?listPreferredItemPaddingRight">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Masala Dosa"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/priceTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$15/ltr"
        android:layout_below="@id/nameTextView"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/plusButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/priceTextView"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/minusButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/priceTextView"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numberTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/minusButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/minusButton"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/plusButton"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/minusButton"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And lastly, the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'android.widget.TextView com.ranjusrecipebox.nalapaka.MainActivity$ViewHolder.numberTextView' on a null object reference
                                                                                at com.ranjusrecipebox.nalapaka.MainActivity$ViewHolder.access$502(MainActivity.java:158)
                                                                                at com.ranjusrecipebox.nalapaka.MainActivity$ItemAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:195)
                                                                                at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2363)
                                                                                at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1970)
                                                                                at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:704)
                                                                                at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:668)
                                                                                at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5186)
                                                                                at android.widget.ListView.trackMotionScroll(ListView.java:1889)
                                                                                at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3568)
                                                                                at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:3977)
                                                                                at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3802)
                                                                                at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:10023)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2626)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2307)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:413)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1808)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3061)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:375)
                                                                                at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10243)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4438)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4306)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3853)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3906)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3872)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3999)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4056)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3853)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3906)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3872)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3853)
02-19 21:24:39.687 7299-7299/com.ranjusrecipebox.nalapaka E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6246)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6220)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6181)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6349)
                                                                                at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
                                                                                at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:6320)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6372)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:615)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Hi @Aadit, can you please try remove + sign in numberTextView from those ids       android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/minusButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/minusButton"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/plusButton"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/minusButton"

Comment: You are not very clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (convertView != null) { 
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
} else { 
    convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false); 
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.nameTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView); 
    holder.priceTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.priceTextView); 
    holder.plusButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.plusButton); 
    holder.minusButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.minusButton); 
    holder.numberTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.numberTextView); 
    convertView.setTag(holder);
}
```

Try doing this.

Comment: While the change is valid, still no difference

Comment: if your convert view is not null then you are taking it from tag() but if it is null and when you are creating it you need to do setTag() as well

Comment: if your convert view is not null then you are taking it from tag() but if it is null and when you are creating it you need to do setTag() as well

Comment: any time dude✌️

Answer (score 1):

You are facing this exception because you have not set the tag but you are retrieving holder when liistview scrolls so it returns null on this line

```
holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag():
```

Set the tag after creating view holder object like this

```
convertView.setTag(holder);
```

Comment: Valid but not functional, again